# Como definir um alias global no BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Estou utilizando o `Terminal` no `Linux` e estou cansado de ficar repetindo os mesmos comandos toda hora.

Por exemplo, eu uso um comando praticamente o dia inteiro, daí eu crio um alias para poder facilitar as coisas.

Exemplo:

```
  alias tt="php artisan tinker --env=local"

  alias artisan="php artisan --env=local"
```

Porém, toda vez que o `Terminal` é encerrado, esses atalhos "vão para o saco". Daí eu tenho que definir tudo de novo quando abro o `Terminal` de novo  ou reinicio o meu `Ubuntu`;

Como posso fazer para deixar esses `Aliases` globais? Tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Podem falar que não é "dentro do escopo", mas que uso isso todo dia para programar, uso!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode acrescentar essas linhas no arquivo `/etc/profile`, Assim que o usuário efetuar o login, as informações são carregadas.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/profile
ou
$ sudo nano /etc/profile
```

profile:

```
#...
alias tt="php artisan tinker --env=local"
alias artisan="php artisan --env=local"
```

> Para aplicar as alterações, deve efetuar o logout.

Comment: Apenas relembrando @Brumazzi DB que basta fazer `$source /etc/profile` ou `#source /etc/profile` que já atualiza e torna desnecessário efetuar o logout.

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho, sim mas isso só se aplica no terminal que foi feito o `source`, caso abra outro terminal a configuração não é aplicada, por isso a sugestão do logout.

Comment: sem problemas, foi só para implementar! mas pelo que eu saiba se abrir outro terminal ele ja vem carregado, pelo menos no meu com Scientific Linux, mas vou testar numa maquina que tenho aqui das crianças ver filmes e que usa o ubuntu.

Comment: opa, tens razão @Brumazzi DB
testei lá no ubuntu, precisa mesmo efetuar logout
mas no meu com RHEL nunca precisei

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho, Algumas distribuições vem com o `.bashrc` ou o `.profile` pré-configurados, provavelmente o seu já importa as configurações diretamente do `/etc/profile` por causa dessas configurações.

Comment: Isso seria global para todos os usuários? Será que é isso mesmo que ele quer?

Answer (score 3):

Coloca os teus aliases dentro do arquivo `/home/$USER/.bashrc` .

Este arquivo é executado todas as vezes que você abrir um terminal gráfico.

Adicione, preferencialmente, os seus aliases no final do arquivo.

Por exemplo, você pode usar o `nano` para editar esse arquivo:

```
 sudo  nano /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

Aí você pode adicionar qualquer alias:

```
artisan="php artisan --env=local"
```